# How to find all vectors so that a vector equation can be solved?

Tags: linear-algebra

Unfortunately, my text book doesn't clarify this process at all.  It's asking to find all all vectors [a b] so that the vector equation can be solved.  The vector equation is:

$c1$ $[3,1]$ + $c2 [6,2]$=$[a, b]$

The linear system would look like:

$3c1+6c2=a$

$c1+2c2=b$

My text doesn't give any indication how to solve this and I'm stuck.  Any help would be appreciated!  Also, apologies since I can't get the vector forms inserted properly!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

You have two equations, and two variables (we treat a, b as constants). Set up the associated augmented coefficient matrix, row reduce, and solve for $c_1, c_2$, which can each be expressed as functions of $a, b$. From that, you should also be able to express $a, b$ as functions of the constants $c_1, c_2$.

Associated augmented coefficient matrix to your system of equations:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 6 &\mid& a\\ 1 & 2 & \mid & b\end{pmatrix}$$

**TIP**: Be sure to choose a value for $b$ that will ensure the system is **consistent**.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering!  I think I figured it out!  I row reduced to where the bottom row equaled:

$0 0 |-1/3a+b$
I then solved for b, getting $1/3a=b$, meaning all vectors should be of the form $[a, 1/3a]$.  Does that look right?

Comment: Your welcome.  Yes indeed, that looks right!

Comment: @amWhy: A nice number of accepts for you today! +1